# How to pivot a Key/Value style table into a normal table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, crosstab, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to convert the following table into something the is a bit easier to query. The historical data is important so it cannot get thrown away and there is an indefinite number of options for Variable (I only need some of them in the final result).

> This is almost exactly what I need to do but it doesn't account for the historical data and assumes that the Variables are unique to the User_ID in my case a user_ID may have 3 or 4 of the same variable and I need the newest one.
>   See > [MySQL Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997710/mysql-pivot-table-problem)

```
| UUID   |UUID_User |Variable  |Value     |DateSet              |
|--------|----------|----------|----------|---------------------|
| X123Y  |123XX12   |FirstName |Jane      | 2011-07-09 14:13:12 |
| X126Y  |123XX12   |LastName  |Jones     | 2011-07-09 14:13:12 |
| X173Y  |123XX62   |FirstName |Joe       | 2011-07-09 14:11:12 |
| X143Y  |123XX62   |LastName  |Smith     | 2011-07-09 14:11:12 |
| X129Y  |123XX12   |LastName  |Smith     | 2011-11-09 14:13:12 | << Jane Gets Married
```

Transform the above into (making sure to use the newest lastname entry for jane)

```
|UUID_User |FirstName |LastName  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|123XX12   |Jane      |Smith     |
|123XX62   |John      |Smith     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the most recent entry per user is a common problem that is often tagged `greatest-n-per-group` on Stack Overflow.  I suggest creating a VIEW for this, though it isn't strictly necessary.

```
CREATE VIEW LatestKeyValue AS
 SELECT k1.*
 FROM KeyValue AS k1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN KeyValue AS k2
  ON (k1.UUID_User, k1.Variable) = (k2.UUID_User, k2.Variable) 
  AND k1.DateSet < k2.DateSet
 WHERE k2.DateSet IS NULL
```

Then you can pivot that for each variable you need in a couple of different ways such as the following:

```
SELECT UUID_User, 
  MAX(CASE Variable WHEN 'FirstName' THEN Value END) AS FirstName,
  MAX(CASE Variable WHEN 'LastName' THEN Value END) AS LastName
FROM LatestKeyValue
GROUP BY UUID_User
```

Comment: BINGO, that view was exactly what I needed to see where I was going wrong. This did exactly what I needed thank you.

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko, I don't use MariaDB. But you're right, I made a mistake in my SQL syntax, I think I've corrected it. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @BillKarwin MariaDB is just a fully backwards-compatible MySQL fork, which comes with newest Ubuntu installations as well as XAMPP. Thank you for your correction, I've lifted the downvote.